# Out of Stack Space in Function

Tags: excel, function, error-handling, runtime-error, stack-overflow

I have problem in my listcode.
In my code, the function f(x) was repeating over and over again, while I just need f(x1) and f(x2).

Here is the detail

```
Function f(x)
    f(x) = tan(x) - ((Cells(16, 2).Value) * (Cells(8, 6).Value)) / (2 * (Cells(4, 2).Value) * (Cells(4, 2).Value) * Cos(x) * Cos(x))
End Function

Sub SolusiNumSudutElevasi()

Dim xm, ym As Double
Dim g, pi As Double
Dim v0, x1, x2, xS As Double
Dim slope, error, i As Double

error = 0.000001
g = Cells(16, 2).Value
pi = Cells(15, 2).Value
v0 = Cells(4, 2).Value
xm = Cells(8, 6).Value
ym = Cells(9, 6).Value

'memasukkan x0,x1
x1 = Cells(13, 6).Value / 180 * pi
x2 = Cells(14, 6).Value / 180 * pi

'hitung slope
slope = (f(x1) - f(x2)) / (x1 - x2)

'hitung x2, setup counter iterasi
xS = x1 - (f(x1) / slope)
i = 0

'Bila f(theta) = 0 maka theta adalah akarnya
'Bila tidak, cari dengan metode Secant

If f(x1) = 0 Then
    Cells(15, 6).Value = x1
ElseIf f(x2) = 0 Then
    Cells(15, 6).Value = x2
ElseIf f(xS) = 0 Then
    Cells(15, 6).Value = xS
Else
    Do While (Abs((xS - x2) / xS) > error) And (f(xS) <> 0)
        x1 = x2
        x2 = xS
        i = i + 1
        slope = (f(x1) - f(x2)) / (x1 - x2)
        xS = x1 - (f(x1)) / slope
    Loop
    Cells(15, 6).Value = xS
End If


End Sub
```

In my code, the function is never ending repeating. WHat is wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, change your function to

```
f = Tan(x) - ((Cells(16, 2).Value) * (Cells(8, 6).Value)) / (2 * (Cells(4, 2).Value) * (Cells(4, 2).Value) * Cos(x) * Cos(x))
```

You need to set the return value equal to the name of the function without the arguments. The way you have it now is probably calling the function over and over.

Next, declaring variable like

```
Dim xm, ym As Double
```

is the same as

```
Dim xm as Variant, ym As Double
```

You probably meant to

```
Dim xm as Double, ym As Double
```

Unfortunately you have to explicitly type every variable. There is no shortcut.

Comment: Ah I see. Thankss. But this code just find 1 root. How can be? Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Consider making a new question on SO.